# MacOS Safari rendering bug after html popup window. Why?

Tags: html, css, macos, safari

I took the HTML5 Boilerplate template and created a sample page that shows rendering bug in Safari on Mac OS http://random.net.ua/bug/

To reproduce the error:

1. Click "Open window"
2. Scroll to the bottom of the window
3. Click anywhere on the page
4. Scroll to the top

You will see something like this:
[image: bug]

Answer (score 1):

For me the site works fine, not like what your site looks like.
Perhaps try clearing your cookies/ history in order to make the change take effect on your computer?

Hope that helps. Also posting code can lead to a better answer :D